# Loading objects instantiated during runtime from one scene to another in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game where the player creates objects (blocks) in a "set up" scene and then when the timer ends, I'd like those objects, including their transform values to be loaded into a new scene.  How would I go about loading objects created during runtime into a new scene?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DontDestroyOnLoad is a valuable way to achieve this.
What you could also do is the following:

Create an Empty object called "Cross-Scene-Objects" and add a script to it, make it so it doesn't destroy on load. Then simply child any objects to that object, and remove objects as you see fit.

You could also make the CrossSceneObjects script a singleton class and have some basic AddObject and RemoveObject methods which handle putting the game objects under the object.

If you only want certain objects in certain scenes, you could use the method above but add some further logic to set game objects active if you're in the scene you want them to show up in.

I have no example code, but if this is not enough for you to work off I can happily edit to provide code examples :) My style is to first provide the solution steps rather than the code to give you  a starting point.